# Can a particular file on a server be made visible to a specific set of scripts, but return a 404 error when accessed by URL?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, include

I have files to be included (`include()`) in certain scripts. If someone were to enter the path to the file through the browser as the URL, however, I want the server to serve a 404 error. How would I do this?

Comment: Place the file outside the doc root.

Answer (score 0):

```
# map 403 to 404 error page, prob. not a good idea...
ErrorDocument 403 /error/404.html

<Files *.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files index.php>     # <- allow direct access to index.php only
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Perhaps a better way is to define a constant in your `index.php` file and check if that constant is defined in the other scripts. If not, return 404 status and display a 404 template.

Comment: I mean to have a custom 404 page (using htaccess) to direct to upon 404, which is easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

Place the files somewhere outside the document root. Access from the web won't find it but scripts will still be able to use the absolute file path within the local system.

```
/-- home -- docroot -- index.php 
     |
     +- scripts -- myscript.php
```

`http://www.example.com` gets `index.php` from `/home/docroot`

`index.php` includes `/home/scripts/myscript.php`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  My first recommendation would be to move all the files that you don't intend to actually be served via web server out of the web server root.

If you can't or won't do that, you can certainly use Apache .conf file or .htaccess to restrict access to certain directories or files that you don't want to be accessed.

If you don't have access to the server config, you can add some simple code at the top of each include file to return a 404 header if the file was not accessed in a proper manner (usually done by setting some flag on page that would include the file and testing that flag within the include file).